# N log(N) or N clarification

Tags: performance, big-o, time-complexity

Will performing a O(log N) algorithm N times give O(N log(N))? Or is it O(N)?

e.g. Inserting N elements into a self-balancing tree.

```
int i = 0;
while (i++ < N) {
    insert(itemsToInsert[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely O(N log(N)).  It COULD also be O(N), if you could show that the sequence of calls, as a total, grows slow enough (because while SOME calls are O(log N), enough others are fast enough, say O(1), to bring the total down).

Remember: O(f) means the algorithm is no SLOWER than f, but it can be faster (even if just in certain cases).

Answer (score 1):

N times O(log(N)) leads to O(N log(N)).

Answer (score 1):

Big-O notation notates the asymptotic behavior of the algorithm.  The cost of each additional step is `O(log N)`; we know that for an `O(N)` algorithm, the cost of each additional step is `O(1)` and asymptotically the cost function bound is a straight line.

Therefore `O(N)` is too low of a bound; `O(N log N)` seems about right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Calculus really helps here.  The first iteration is complexity log(1), the second iteration is log(2), &ct until the Nth iteration which is log(N).  Rather than thinking of the problem as a multiplication, think of it as an integral...

[image]

This happens to come out as O(N log(N)), but that is kind of a coincidence.